# New fonts not showing in Photoshop - how to refresh font list?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I install new fonts to my Fonts folder in Windows, I usually do so whilst Photoshop is open. Is there any way to refresh/rescan/reload the font list without restarting Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Photoshop open, it will not automatically update your font list.

To refresh the fonts without restarting Photoshop, do the following:

- Open the character window (Window -> Character)
- Click the dropdown menu in the top right and press ‘Reset Character’

The fonts will now be updated with those on your system.

[image]